# Get href Attribute Link from td tag BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new in Python and someone suggested me to use Beautiful soup for Scrapping and i am struck  in a problem to fetch the href attribute from a td tag Column 2 on the basis of year in column 4.

```
<table class="tableFile2" summary="Results">
         <tr>
            <th width="7%" scope="col">Filings</th>
            <th width="10%" scope="col">Format</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th width="10%" scope="col">Filing Date</th>
            <th width="15%" scope="col">File/Film Number</th>
         </tr>
<tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap">8-K</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><a href="/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312513199324/0001193125-13-199324-index.htm" id="documentsbutton">&nbsp;Documents</a></td>
<td class="small" >Current report, items 8.01 and 9.01
<br />Acc-no: 0001193125</td>
            <td>2013-05-03</td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap"><a href="/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&amp;filenum=000-10030&amp;owner=include&amp;count=40">000-10030</a><br>13813281         </td>
         </tr>
<tr class="blueRow">
<td nowrap="nowrap">424B2</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><a href="/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312513191849/0001193125-13-191849-index.htm" id="documentsbutton">&nbsp;Documents</a></td>
<td class="small" >Prospectus [Rule 424(b)(2)]<br />Acc-no: 0001193125</td>
            <td>2013-05-01</td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap"><a href="/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&amp;filenum=333-188191&amp;owner=include&amp;count=40">333-188191</a><br>13802405         </td>
         </tr>
<tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap">FWP</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><a href="/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312513189053/0001193125-13-189053-index.htm" id="documentsbutton">&nbsp;Documents</a></td>
<td class="small" >Filing under Securities Act Rules 163/433 of free writing prospectuses<br />Acc-no: 0001193125-13-189053&nbsp;(34 Act)&nbsp; Size: 52 KB            </td>
            <td>2013-05-01</td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap"><a href="/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&amp;filenum=333-188191&amp;owner=include&amp;count=40">333-188191</a><br>13800170         </td>
         </tr>
</table>



table = soup.find('table', class="tableFile2")

rows = table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
  cols = tr.findAll('td')
  if "2013" in cols[3]
    link = cols[1].find('a').get('href')
  print
```

Comment: So you want data from columns `Format` and `Filing Date`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This works for me in Python 2.7:

```
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tableFile2'})
rows = table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    if len(cols) >= 4 and "2013" in cols[3].text:
        link = cols[1].find('a').get('href')
        print link
```

A few issues with your previous code:

1. `soup.find()` requires a dictionary of attributes (e.g., `{'class' : 'tableFile2'}`)
2. Not every `cols` instance will have at least 3 columns, so you need to check length first.