# How to scrape links inside td tags in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the `html` code that I found from a website.
I want the [vk link](https://vk.com/doc722551386_632783806?hash=gjIfCA0ILqZ1LQlzftCyxZ4zOATANYnUqZXiZ1vsAJH&dl=5wFKrFiIzvVfYJ6M4m1z9ALqKzGdXJdsGAXv1NaBtSg) which is found inside the `td` tag.

I tried so many ways in python to scrape that link but it always shows some type of error and sometimes it shows different links.

```
<thead>
<tr class="footable-header">
<th scope="col" 
class="ninja_column_0 
ninja_clmn_nm_date ">Date</th><th scope="col"class="ninja_column_1ninja_clmn_nm_download">download</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr data-row_id="0" 
class="ninja_table_row_0 nt_row_id_0"><td>01-05-2022</td><td>https://vk.com/doc722551386_632783806? hash=gjIfCA0ILqZ1LQlzftCyxZ4zOATANYnUqZXiZ1vsAJH&dl=5wFKrFiIzvVfYJ6M4m1z9ALqKzGdXJdsGAXv1NaBtSg</td> </tr>
```

Here is the `python` code that I tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://www.careerswave.in/dainik-jagran-newspaper-download/"
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text,'html.parser')
f = open("vkdain.txt", "w")
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
data = link.get('href')
print(data)
```

Comment: You should probably fix the last two lines to be indented (just a small fix) [How to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get the links in `td` this worked for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.careerswave.in/dainik-jagran-newspaper-download/"
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
f = open("vkdain.txt", "w")
for link in soup.find_all("td"): # find all the td's
    if link.text.startswith('https://vk'): # check if the pattern is the one you want
        print(link.text)
```

This gets you the following result:

```
https://vk.com/doc722551386_632783806?hash=gjIfCA0ILqZ1LQlzftCyxZ4zOATANYnUqZXiZ1vsAJH&dl=5wFKrFiIzvVfYJ6M4m1z9ALqKzGdXJdsGAXv1NaBtSg
https://vk.com/doc722551386_632705478?hash=mXInLmfkZNSLz5UVqRoRW60bRlzynUFUpRZoiBeW4ko&dl=zFzHm0Edhycg4ulJp33jdeFbypSaynNcjpZ41cUnID0
...
https://vk.com/doc623586997_607921843?hash=c6f706ee5f09f4d4e5&dl=f780520e509b9f671b
https://vk.com/doc623586997_607809766?hash=ef486a0fb1e873640e&dl=eeb60781cef9e58541
```

Here are some related questions:

- [Python BeautifulSoup - How to crawl links <a> inside values in <td>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70232208/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-crawl-links-a-inside-values-in-td)
- [Get href Attribute Link from td tag BeautifulSoup Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733109/get-href-attribute-link-from-td-tag-beautifulsoup-python)